# Three.js skew or deform Texture on a face

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, textures

i want to make a panoramic viewer for a specific image format.
A hole panoramic image consists of 8 by 4 images.

my Idea was to make a Sphere with

`geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 500,8, 4 );`

and Texture each face with

```
geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][0] = [ new THREE.Vector2(0.5,1),new THREE.Vector2(0,0),new THREE.Vector2(1,0) ] ;    
geometry.faces[0].materialIndex = 7;
```

and so on.

The Problem is, the first and the last Ring have only 1 face per image.

[Example Image](http://picload.org/image/crorppr/screenshot2014-09-1714.39.18.png)

is it possible to skew or deform the Texture, so that the upper right und upper left corner are at the top of the face and not cut out of the Texture like at the Example Image?

[Texture with Example Cut out](http://picload.org/image/crorppw/testuv-kopie.jpg)